# Adding NuGet ndef library to windows phone 8 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nfc, windows-phone-8, ndef

So I tried to add the NDEF library for proximity application in Visual Studio 2012 for a Windows Phone 8 app. In `Package Manager` I checked `Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build` and in the `Solution Explorer` I selected `Enable NuGet Package Restore`.

So far so good, but when i try to install the package I get the following error:

> Could not install package '**NdefLibrary 0.9.0.1**'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '**WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0**', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework.  For more information, contact the package author.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fine on my dev box. Here's the output from my NuGet package manager on a WP8 project:

```
PM> Install-Package NdefLibrary
You are downloading NdefLibrary from Andreas Jakl, the license agreement to which is available at https://ndef.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'NdefLibrary 0.9.0.1'.
Successfully added 'NdefLibrary 0.9.0.1' to Wp8TestApp.
```

What you're probably missing is to update your NuGet package manager to the latest version. Go to Visual Studio File Menu --> Tools --> Extensions and Updates --> Updates --> Visual Studio Gallery --> NuGet --> Update and finally you'll need to restart. The reason why this update is needed is that the NuGet version that ships with VS2012 RTM doesn't support WP8 since WP8 didn't RTM before VS2012 did.