# Windows Phone 8: Listen for Bluetooth-Connections

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to **listen** for incomming bluetooth-connections from an Android-device to my WindowsPhone8-device

Is there any way to do that?

(for WP8 -> WP8 connections I could use the PeerFinder, but it won't work for Android / [any other device] -> WP8 connections).

Comment: Did you look for Android Bluetooth Chat sample project?

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I'm searching for a solution for WP8 (like BluetoothListener or sth. like that)

Answer (score 1):

The NFC on Windows Phone 8 are NDEF compatible  "NFC Data Exchange Format" so this should be possible.  I would check out the NDEF Library on codeplex to see if they have something "wrapped" in there to help you out.

http://ndef.codeplex.com/

You an also add it using Nuget

[Adding NuGet ndef library to windows phone 8 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project)

Finally, this article talks about connecting Android to Windows 8 via NFC it should be the same for WP8

http://www.lewisbenge.net/index.php/2012/09/connecting-android-and-windows-8-via-nfc/