# Install-Package: Could not install package WPtoolkit error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding NuGet ndef library to windows phone 8 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project)

While trying to install the WPtoolkit i get the following error...

```
PM> Install-Package WPtoolkit
Successfully installed 'WPtoolkit 4.2012.10.30'.
Successfully uninstalled 'WPtoolkit 4.2012.10.30'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'WPtoolkit 4.2012.10.30'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the packag
e does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
```

Is there something that am i missing?
The NuGet is updated to the latest version too...

Comment: The message clearly states that the library is not compatible for WP8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A ha!

At the FAQ's section...

Q - I have WP8 SDK and I installed the NuGet package, it is still installing the 7.1 version of the toolkit assembly, or I get an error – “You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework.”

```
A – You have an older version of NuGet. 
Install the latest NuGet from www.NuGet.org . Close and restart all the 
instances of Visual Studio. 
Now install the package. It will install correctly. 
WP8 projects are supported from Nuget 2.1 onwards.
```

After that go to xaml page type