# Change path of a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, html-agility-pack

I have a problem with HtmlAgilityPack. I found solution to that problem which is changing reference to another assembly ([Why can't I use htmlagilitypack with windows phone 8? What else can I use to Parse HTML in WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164504/why-cant-i-use-htmlagilitypack-with-windows-phone-8-what-else-can-i-use-to-par)).

The problem I have that I cannot change path of the package as it is greyed out. The picture bellow shows it.[image]

Comment: In order to change the path to that reference you will need to remove it and re-add it. You cannot change the Path directly from the Properties window.

Comment: When installing new package, it doesn't let me choose path. There is only Instal button and package just installs.

Comment: Correct you cannot choose the path. NuGet will look at your project's target framework and pick the assembly from the NuGet package that is the best match. The answer you linked so suggests to "manually removing the reference to the HtmlAgilityPack DLL and referencing the binary in the sl3-wp folder removes the dependency problem". To do that you would need to do that yourself without using NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to control which folder the packages are installed into.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/215

See Phil Haack's comment on Dec 10 2010 at 11:45 PM (in the work item/the link above). The support is partially implemented in 1.0, but is not documented.

According to @dfowler: Add a nuget.config file next to the solution with this:

{some path here}

There is a nuget package for creating the package folder override.

Update for version 2.1

There is now official documentation on how to control the package locations. The release notes for 2.1 specifies the following configuration in a nuget.config file (see the release notes for a description of valid places to put the config files and how the hierarchical configuration model works):

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\thePathToMyPackagesFolder" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

This would change the packages folder for the configuration level you put the file in (solution if you put it in the solution directory, project in project directory and so on). Note that the release notes state:

If you have an existing packages folder underneath your solution root, you will need to delete it before NuGet will place packages in the new location.