# Any good good way to let the user know?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 7 we had this great ToastPrompt (http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) but Windows Phone 8 does not support this great library and I wonder is there is other tools that does the job?

It was a great tool to let the user know stuff (background jobs completing etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes you think WP8 doesn't support Coding4Fun toolkit? Works fine on my computer.

```cs
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new ToastPrompt()
        {
            Title = "hello world",
            Message = "sup stackoverflow?"
        }.Show();
    }
```

When I run the above code snippet it works just fine on WP8:

[image: ToastPrompt on WP8]

If you're having problems with WP8 and NuGet see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project/13353550#13353550). If you're having problems adding a reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698094/referencing-zxing-net-library/13698737#13698737).

Comment: Does it work along the Windows Phone toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Is your app in XAML? You can easily write your own in-App "Toast" by creating a rectangle, and adding a few lines of text to it.

If you're looking to do it while your app is in the background, you can use the [ShellToast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) library built into WP8