# Windows Phone 8 Push Notification (MPNS) Server Code

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

Windows Phone 7 has the MpnsRecipe NuGet package which you can use to send push notification messages to the Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) on the server side. However, this package has not been updated for Windows Phone 8.

http://nuget.org/packages/MpnsRecipe

What is the equivelant for Windows Phone 8? I want to make use of the new wide tiles but I can't find any code online to get me started. All I can find is the XML format for the new messages on MSDN and I'd rather not have to write my own if there is a ready made package available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out PushSharp: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp It appears to have been updated for the new notification payload formats in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

Most WP7 projects should just work on WP8. Did you try to use the NuGet package and something didn't work? Did you [forgot to unblock the web downloaded DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698094/referencing-zxing-net-library/13698737#13698737) or did you forgot to update your [NuGet package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project/13353550#13353550).

Comment: The nuget packages I've found are all for Windows Phone 7 and not 8. I want to be able to push wide tiles to the users. The old Windows Phone 7 nuget packages that I've found do not support this.

Comment: OK, then modify the format of the WP push notification yourself. The format is listed here @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I had assumed that somebody had already done this (WP8 SDK has been available for a while now). Maybe I was wrong. Ok, please update your answer, and I'll mark it as the answer.