# How to User JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6) in Window Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, json.net

I am getting following error when I try to install the Json.Net package.

**Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Can anyone suggest how to I use the JSON.Net In windows phone 8.
I am using **Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Phone** as a Development IDE.

Thanks.

Comment: Please Visit follwing link.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project

Comment: Did you update your NuGet Package Manager? Please update it first and then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure your visual studio installation and NuGet are up to date with the latest updates/patches/versions.
Older versions of NuGet don't know about Windows Phone 8.