# vs2012 add reference and nuget error

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development. I need to add a library which is [imapx](https://imapx.codeplex.com/) to use imap protocol in an app. I think there is something I missed, because I always got an error which is the following :

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'ImapX 2.0.0.9'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I've created a simple project, doing nothing for now, targetting Windows Phone 8 phones. I'm using VS2012, and I tried to install it with Nuget, or adding a reference to the .dll, nothink worked. I installed the update3 of VS2012, but it not works too.

Nuget Package Manager is version 2.7. I've seen some post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342630/adding-nuget-ndef-library-to-windows-phone-8-project) and another where people say to update package manager, but I have no updates for Nuget.

Thanks for your help.
Hope I'm clear...

Audric

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the ImapX library, today I released ImapX 2.0.0.13, which now supports Windows Phone 7.1 and 8.0. You can install it using Nuget or downloading it from [codeplex](https://imapx.codeplex.com/).

Best regards,

Pavel Azanov